# MySql date one day split

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to do a very simple java web app which allows to informations of a person: fristname, surname, date of birth and store them in a MySql db.
The issue is that when I try to insert a date(e.g.07/03/2019), on db the date is one day before(06/03/2019).
How is it possible to fix that?
Below the code:

**The bean**

```
package bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

public class Persona implements Serializable {

private int idPersona;
private String nome;
private String cognome;
private Date dataNascita;

public Persona() {
    super();

}

public Persona(String nome, String cognome, Date dataNascita) {
    super();
    this.nome = nome;
    this.cognome = cognome;
    this.dataNascita = dataNascita;
}

public Persona(int idPersona, String nome, String cognome, Date dataNascita) 
{
    super();
    this.idPersona = idPersona;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.cognome = cognome;
    this.dataNascita = dataNascita;
}

public int getIdPersona() {
    return idPersona;
}

public void setIdPersona(int idPersona) {
    this.idPersona = idPersona;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getCognome() {
    return cognome;
}

public void setCognome(String cognome) {
    this.cognome = cognome;
}

public Date getDataNascita() {
    return dataNascita;
}

public void setDataNascita(Date dataNascita) {
    this.dataNascita = dataNascita;
}

}
```

**The servlet**

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import bean.Persona;
import dao.ProvaDao;
import utility.ManipolazioneDate;


@WebServlet("/Inserimento")
public class Inserimento extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public Inserimento() {


}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
    String cognome = request.getParameter("cognome");
    String dataNascita = request.getParameter("dataNascita");
    Date dataN = null;
    try {
        dataN = (Date) ManipolazioneDate.convertiData(dataNascita);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Persona p = new Persona(nome, cognome, dataN);
    System.out.println(p.getNome());
    System.out.println(p.getCognome());
    System.out.println(p.getDataNascita());

    try{
        ProvaDao.registraPersona(p);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}
**A class with a static method to parse a String date format into a java.sql.Date format**

```
package utility;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class ManipolazioneDate {

public static Date convertiData(String data) throws ParseException{

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date parser = format.parse(data);
    java.sql.Date dataSql = new java.sql.Date(parser.getTime());

    return dataSql;

}

}
```

**Dao**

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import bean.Persona;
import utility.Connessione;

public class ProvaDao {

    public static void registraPersona(Persona persona) throws SQLException{

        Connection conn = Connessione.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;


        String ins = "insert into prova2.persona(nome, cognome, dataNascita) 
values(?,?,?)";

        try{

            ps = conn.prepareStatement(ins);

            ps.setString(1, persona.getNome());
            ps.setString(2, persona.getCognome());
            ps.setDate(3, persona.getDataNascita());

            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Persona inserita");

        }catch(SQLException e){

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Errore nell'inserimento");

        }finally{

            if(ps != null){
                ps.close();
            }

            if(conn != null){
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**JSP with form**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div align="center">
  <form action="/Prova/Inserimento" method="get">
   <p>Nome</p>
   <input type="text" value="" name="nome">
   <br>
   <p>Cognome</p>
   <input type="text" value"" name="cognome">
   <br>
   <p>Data di nascita</p>
   <input type="text" value="" name="dataNascita">
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Invia">
   
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe code is not wrong. Confirm timezone at your MySQL server.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe code is not wrong. (Because code does not manipulate datetime.)

At java code, do `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` get and check the timestamp. If the timestamp is wrong, it is due to MySQL server.

Comment: Ok done! Now the date is correct(2019-03-08) but time is not. Here in Italy it's 11:51AM but on MySql it's 04:50:12